# Google.logInAsync function for OAuth not doing anything in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

`Google.logInAsync` function which is supposed to used for OAuth in React Native, is not giving any response, or is stuck. Take a look at my code, from line 14 to 36. This `signIn` function is calling `Google.logInAsync` and is stuck there. No error, nothing. How ever when I press the button again, and the signIn function gets called again, an error is passed: `Error: Cannot start a new task while another task is currently in progress: Get Auth`

This is my code currently. It shows a label " Sign In With Google" and a Button on the screen. Tapping on the button starts `this.signIn` funtion, prints "Started logInAsync" on the debugger screen, but  the`Google.logInAsync` never completes, no errors are thrown anywhere. `console.log('Completed logInAsync')` never gets executed!

```
import {Google} from "expo"
...
            console.log('Starting logInAsync')
            const result = await Google.logInAsync({
                androidClientId:
                "<CLIENT_ID>",
                scopes: ["profile", "email"]
            })
            console.log('Completed logInAsync')
```

that gave an error saying install "expo-google-app-auth"
I installed that module and then changed the import and the function

```
import * as Google from "expo-google-app-auth"
...
            console.log('Starting logInAsync')
            const result = await Google.logInAsync({
            ...
            })
            console.log('Completed logInAsync')
```

And after there,

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image, Button } from "react-native"
import * as Google from "expo-google-app-auth"

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      signedIn: false,
      name: "",
      photoUrl: ""
    }
  }
  signIn = async () => {
    try {
      console.log('Starting logInAsync')
      const result = await Google.logInAsync({
        androidClientId:
          "860657237026-jfosg5hu52u1vedclccs1vgihghva534.apps.googleusercontent.com",
        scopes: ["profile", "email"]
      })
      console.log('Completed logInAsync')

      if (result.type === "success") {
        this.setState({
          signedIn: true,
          name: result.user.name,
          photoUrl: result.user.photoUrl
        })
      } else {
        console.log("Cancelled!")
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log("Error: ", e)
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {this.state.signedIn ? (
          <LoggedInPage name={this.state.name} photoUrl={this.state.photoUrl} />
        ) : (
          <LoginPage signIn={this.signIn} />
        )}
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const LoginPage = props => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text style={styles.header}>Sign In With Google</Text>
      <Button title="Sign in with Google" onPress={() => props.signIn()} />
    </View>
  )
}

const LoggedInPage = props => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.header}>Welcome:{props.name}</Text>
      <Image style={styles.image} source={{ uri: props.photoUrl }} />
    </View>
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center"
  },
  header: {
    fontSize: 25
  },
  image: {
    marginTop: 15,
    width: 150,
    height: 150,
    borderColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0.2)",
    borderWidth: 3,
    borderRadius: 150
  }
})
```

No error occur in this code, except if you press the SignIn button twice. I am on the latest version of Node, React-Native and Expo as of now.